# Can't retrieve EmployeeId from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, active-directory

My `GetActiveDirectory()` method is used to get data from Active Directory using the `SamAccountName`, and it's working but the problem is the `user.EmployeeId` return no sign of data.

Why I can't receive the `EmployeeId` and how can I fix it?

This is my codes:

```
public void GetActiveDirectory(DataTable DataStorage, string SamAccountName)
{
        var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(
           ContextType.Domain, null, _ldapPath, _ldapUsername, _ldapPassword);

        var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "Domain Users");

        if (group != null)
        {
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("SamAccountName");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("Surname");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("Guid");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("Enabled");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("GivenName");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("EmailAddress");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("SID");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("DateCreated");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("DateModified");
            DataStorage.Columns.Add("EmployeeNumber");
            DataStorage.AcceptChanges();

            foreach (var p in group.GetMembers(false))
            {
                if(p.SamAccountName != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                            domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, SamAccountName);
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            var userDE = (DirectoryEntry)p.GetUnderlyingObject();
                            DateTime dateCreated = userDE.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value != null
                                ? (DateTime)userDE.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value 
                                : DateTime.MinValue;
                            DateTime dateModified = userDE.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value != null
                                ? (DateTime)userDE.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value 
                                : DateTime.MinValue;
                            DataRow dr = DataStorage.NewRow();
                            dr["SamAccountName"] = user.SamAccountName;
                            dr["Surname"] = user.Surname;
                            dr["Guid"] = user.Guid.ToString();
                            dr["Enabled"] = user.Enabled;
                            dr["GivenName"] = user.GivenName;
                            dr["EmailAddress"] = user.EmailAddress;
                            dr["SID"] = user.Sid.Value;
                            dr["EmployeeNumber"] = user.EmployeeId; //Always give an empty space or null.
                            dr["DateCreated"] = dateCreated;
                            dr["DateModified"] = dateModified;
                            DataStorage.Rows.Add(dr);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `group.GetMembers()` already returns the users - why are you calling `.FindByIdentity()` on each found user again to retrieve the user object?? Doesn't make any sense to me ....

Comment: @marc_s The first `.FIndByIdentity()` is for the groups of users the "Domain Users" group and the second one is used to get one user in "Domain Users" group.

Comment: Yes, I see - but the second one is **pointless** - the `group.GetMembers()` **already** returns the `UserPrincipal` members.... you should just use these - and not go fetch the user *again* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS IS A TEMPORARY ANSWER TO** `UserPrincipal.EmployeeId`

I don't know why `UserPrincipal.EmployeeId` is not working so I decide to use the old way method.

What I've tried to solve my own problem in `.EmployeeId` is to go back using `System.DirectoryServices`

Here is my method to get `EmployeeId` using `System.DirectoryServices`

```
        var oDirecotyrEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
            _ldapPath, _ldapUsername, _ldapPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        SearchResultCollection odrSearchResultCollection;
        var odrUser = new DirectoryEntry();
        var odrDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher
        {Filter = "sAMAccountName="+SamAccountName+"", SearchRoot = oDirecotyrEntry};
        using(odrDirectorySearcher)
        {
            odrSearchResultCollection = odrDirectorySearcher.FindAll();
            if(odrSearchResultCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(SearchResult result in odrSearchResultCollection)
                {
                    var num = result.Properties["employeeNumber"];
                    foreach(var no in num)
                    {
                        dr["EmployeeNumber"] = no.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and to complete my project I use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

```
var oPricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
           ContextType.Domain, _ldapPath2, _ldapUsername, _ldapPassword);
        UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPricipalContext, SamAccountName);
        if (oUserPrincipal != null)
        {
            var oDateTime = (DirectoryEntry)oUserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
            DateTime dateCreated = oDateTime.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value != null
                ? (DateTime)oDateTime.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value
                : DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTime dateChanged = oDateTime.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value != null
                ? (DateTime)oDateTime.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value
                : DateTime.MinValue;
            dr["SamAccountName"] = oUserPrincipal.SamAccountName;
            dr["Surname"] = oUserPrincipal.Surname;
            dr["Guid"] = oUserPrincipal.Guid.ToString();
            dr["Enabled"] = oUserPrincipal.Enabled;
            dr["GivenName"] = oUserPrincipal.GivenName;
            dr["EmailAddress"] = oUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
            dr["SID"] = oUserPrincipal.Sid.Value;
            dr["DateCreated"] = dateCreated;
            dr["DateModified"] = dateChanged;
            DataStorage.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` is require to my project so I need to use it.

**SORRY FOR MY GRAMMAR.**

Here is my full code.

No snippet format???

```
 using System.DirectoryServices;
 using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

 public void GetUsers(DataTable DataStorage, string SamAccountName)
    {   
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("SamAccountName");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("Surname");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("Guid");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("Enabled");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("GivenName");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("EmailAddress");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("SID");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("DateCreated");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("DateModified");
        DataStorage.Columns.Add("EmployeeNumber");
        DataStorage.AcceptChanges();
        DataRow dr = DataStorage.NewRow();
        //System.DirectoryServices
        var oDirecotyrEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
            _ldapPath, _ldapUsername, _ldapPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        SearchResultCollection odrSearchResultCollection;
        var odrUser = new DirectoryEntry();
        var odrDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher
        {Filter = "sAMAccountName="+SamAccountName+"", SearchRoot = oDirecotyrEntry};
        using(odrDirectorySearcher)
        {
            odrSearchResultCollection = odrDirectorySearcher.FindAll();
            if(odrSearchResultCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(SearchResult result in odrSearchResultCollection)
                {
                    var num = result.Properties["employeeNumber"];
                    foreach(var no in num)
                    {
                        dr["EmployeeNumber"] = no.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
        var oPricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(
           ContextType.Domain, _ldapPath2, _ldapUsername, _ldapPassword);
        UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPricipalContext, SamAccountName);
        if (oUserPrincipal != null)
        {
            var oDateTime = (DirectoryEntry)oUserPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
            DateTime dateCreated = oDateTime.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value != null
                ? (DateTime)oDateTime.Properties["WhenCreated"].Value
                : DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTime dateChanged = oDateTime.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value != null
                ? (DateTime)oDateTime.Properties["WhenChanged"].Value
                : DateTime.MinValue;
            dr["SamAccountName"] = oUserPrincipal.SamAccountName;
            dr["Surname"] = oUserPrincipal.Surname;
            dr["Guid"] = oUserPrincipal.Guid.ToString();
            dr["Enabled"] = oUserPrincipal.Enabled;
            dr["GivenName"] = oUserPrincipal.GivenName;
            dr["EmailAddress"] = oUserPrincipal.EmailAddress;
            dr["SID"] = oUserPrincipal.Sid.Value;
            dr["DateCreated"] = dateCreated;
            dr["DateModified"] = dateChanged;
            DataStorage.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
```